# compare two arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays i.e  primaryNetworkIds and dataArray.
primaryNetworkIds array contains the following data.

```
["10080","10081","10082","98"]
```

dataArray contains the following data

```
[{"Network ID":"10080","Description":"ALPHA"},{"Network ID":"10081","Description":"PASSIVE","Network ID":"10082","Description":"PLANS"}}]
```

I want to compare the Network ID from both arrays and if there are same then the resultant array will be as follows

```
var resultantArray=[];
[{"Network ID":"10080","Description":"ALPHA"},{"Network ID":"10081","Description":"PASSIVE","Network ID":"10082","Description":"PLANS"}}]
```

Please let me know the efficient way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically a question of this nature would be placed on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), not here which is primarily Salesforce.

I can offer a quick solution to this but you will need to address potential exceptions. Your arrays may grow and this suggestion might need to be revisited. PS, I am no expert in JS.

FYI, `dataArray` is invalid JSON. Please use a format/validate tool such as [JsonFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

```
primaryNetworkIds = ["10080","10081","10082","98"];

dataArray = [
{
    "NetworkID":"10080",
    "Description":"ALPHA"
},
{
    "NetworkID":"10081",
    "Description":"PASSIVE"
},
{
    "NetworkID":"10082",
    "Description":"PLANS"
}
];

var resultantArray=[];

for (var i = 0; i < primaryNetworkIds.length; i++) {
    if (dataArray.filter(e => e.NetworkID === primaryNetworkIds[i]).length > 0) {
        resultantArray.push(dataArray[i]);
    }
}

console.log(resultantArray);
```

Comment: your code is working and I am able to get the networkID's with description which are common to both arrays. I am confused here, why you have used only a single loop,? and in the loop should we be checking like this : for (var i=0;i<dataArray.lenght.i++)

Comment: A single loop on `primaryNetworkIds` is used because thats the array you are validating against.

Comment: took some time for me to debug and understand your code and its working perfectly as per my requirement. Now I am able to get unique NetworkIds. Thank you..I